# Is this function continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \mathbb{Q}^2$?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity, piecewise-continuity

Is the following function continuous on the irrationals in $[0,1] \times [0,1]$?
$$f(x,y) =  \begin{cases} 
      0 & x\text{ irrational}\\
      0 & x\text{ rational, }y\text{ irrational}\\
      \frac{1}{q} & x\text{ rational, }y = \frac{p}{q}\text{, lowest terms}
   \end{cases}
$$

I believe that it is, but I'm having a hard time showing why. For any epsilon ball, I think that even $\delta = \epsilon$ probably works, but how do I show that any rational, $\frac{p}{q}$, in $(y - \delta, y+\delta)$ is such that $y-\frac{p}{q} > 0-\frac{1}{q}$, which is how I think I should show continuity.

Comment: What do you mean by irrationals on $[0,1]\times [0,1]$? If you mean the points of the form $(x,y)$ where not both $x,y$ are rational, then $f$ is $0$ on this set, hence continuous.

Comment: That is what I mean, yes. Yes, but how do I show it formally?

Comment: @Levent:  the function is defined on all of $[0,1] \times [0,1]$  The question asks if it is continuous at points where both $x$ and $y$ are irrational.  We need to avoid rational points.

Comment: I still don't get it. Do we ask if it is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2-\mathbb{Q}^2$ or the points where both coordinates are irrational (and in both cases $f$ is constant hence continuous, so what is the question anyway)?

Comment: @Levent: We're asking for each point in $\mathbb R^2\setminus \mathbb Q^2$ whether $f$ is continuous _at that point_. (And the answer is, not always -- $f$ is discontinuous at every point with rational $y$, no matter if $x$ is irrational).

Comment: @HenningMakholm can you elaborate on this a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is continuous on the points where both are irrational.  Choosing a specific $\delta$ is hard, but it is easy to claim it exists.  Given irrational $y$ there are only finitely many rationals in the square with denominators less than $\frac 1\epsilon $  Take $\delta$ less than the distance from $y$ to the closest one and you are home.

Comment: Why are there only finitely many such rationals?

Comment: Because of the restriction to small (less than $\frac 1\epsilon$) denominators.  So there is one with denominator $2$, two with denominator $3$, and so on.  We only care about the $y$ value.

Comment: alright, that makes sense, thanks!

Comment: "Points where both are irrational" are not the same as $\mathbb R^2\setminus\mathbb Q^2$, though.

Comment: Oh wait, I see the issue now. I'm trying to find out if it is continuous whenever at least one is irrational. Is it not true that it is continuous when $x$ irrational, $y$ rational?

Comment: @jackson5: If $y$ is rational, say $y=p/q$, then there are points arbitrarily close to $(x,y)$ where the value of $f$ is $0$, but also points arbitrarily close to $(x,y)$ where the value of $f$ is $1/q$ -- so $f$ cannot be continuous there.

Comment: Right, that makes sense, thank you!